# Cloud Function to sort the Firebase Child from inner child

Tags: android, firebase

I need to have one problem sorted out. I want a cloud function, where I need to loop through every Posts that has uniqueID and I want to sort those uniqueID's according to the value of TotalReactions. To me more vivid, suppose, the first post has totalReactions = 5, and second one has totalReactions = 6, then I need to have another RealTimeDatabase "PostArranged" which sorts them in descending order, so second post which has Total Reaction would be in first and then follows the one which has lesser TotalReaction...
Here is how my firebase realtime database looks like:

```
Posts
 -L29TD-nsUYRu3wYcCQl
     Caption: "First Screenshot"
     CurrentUserReaction: "notreacted"
     Image: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/nep..."
     ReactingUser
        <user-id>:"1"
        <user-id>:"2"
     Time: "13:40:54"
     TotalReactions: "2"
     Unique: "-L29TD-nsUYRu3wYcCQl"
     UserPhoto: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/nep..."
     Username: "Me"
```

Any help would be appreciated ..

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good way to do what you want to do. In this method the database has to be sorted to another "ArrangedDatabase" every time a reaction is added which will happen in a high frequency. So it will be very expensive to do this with Cloud Functions.

Instead use **orderByChild()**, **orderByKey()**, **orderByValue()** to sort data when you're querying data.

[Sorting data - Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sort_data) this show it quite well.

Comment: How can I do that if I am to populate the viewHolder based on child within child and I need to access that inside a child of a child that has unique key as shown above. I need to sort that out based on the totalReactions value... Any help mate?

Comment: Thanks mate.. I figured out the answer!

Comment: Could you please share the answer? I'm having the same problem @Hacker10

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who want to do this in your RecyclerViewAdapter provided by Firebase, it is easily done... When you pass in those 4 parameters. Do not pass the database Reference, instead, make a new query, and make sure to sort that thing either by OrderByChild(), OrderByValue() or anything you want to order by... i.e.
In my case, I will do something like this:

```
q = mDatabaseReference.orderByChild("TotalReactions");
```

and pass q as parameter inside FirebaseAdapter, like this:

```
 FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts,PostViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, PostViewHolder>(
            Posts.class, R.layout.each_post_layout , PostViewHolder.class, q
    ) {
```

.
}